# Creating Iterated Variables in R

Tags: r, loops, iteration, lapply, sapply

I've looked around and seen some questions similar to mine, but none directly on point.  I have a series of presidential election results for various states from 1940 to 2012.  They are labeled, in sequence, r1940, d1940, r1944, d1944, r1948, d1948, and so forth.

I want to create a series of two-party vote variables, which are calculated by dividing the number of Democratic votes by the number of republican and democratic votes. So in a df called votes:

```
d2pv1940 <- (votes$d1940/(votes$d1940+votes$r1940))
```

Obviously I can do this 18 more times by hand, e.g., `d2pv1944<-(votes$d1944/(votes$d1944+votes$r1944))` but obviously that is time consuming and invites errors.  I've seen some solutions to similar problems using lapply or for loops, but I'm not really sure how I'd iterate the four variable names in the commands above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
namest=colnames(votes)
rep=which(substr(namest, 1,1)=="r")
dem=which(substr(namest, 1,1)=="d")

res=votes[,dem]/(votes[,dem]+votes[,rep])
colnames(res)=paste("d2pv",substring(colnames(votes[,dem]),2),sep="")
res
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tidy way to do it:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rex)

data = 
  c(1, 2, 2, 1) %>%
  setNames(
    c("r1940", "d1940", "r1944", "d1944") ) %>%
  as.list %>%
  as.data.frame

regex_1 =
  rex(capture(letter),
      capture(digits) )

abbreviations = data_frame(
  abbreviation = c("d", "r"),
  party = c("democrat", "republican") )

data %>%
  gather(variable, value) %>%
  extract(variable,
          c("abbreviation", "year"),
          regex_1) %>%
  left_join(abbreviations) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  mutate(total = sum(value),
         proportion = value / total ) %>%
  select(-abbreviation, -value) %>%
  spread(party, proportion)
```